# mypy in vscode consumes too much memory

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, mypy

recently I observed VScode is using an insane amount of memory and after some debugging, I realized it was caused by `mypy`. Basically, whenever I opened a python file, mypy launched a python process which quickly increases to more than 20G. The issue will go away only if I turned off `mypy` linting in vscode.

The only related config is this in workspace config file:

```
"python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
"python.linting.mypyArgs": [],
```

VScode version:1.66.2
Python: 3.8
Mypy:  0.910

Comment: You can reach out to its GitHub repo, https://github.com/python/mypy/issues

Comment: I have the same problem. It spawns never ending processes over and over again and consumes all of cpu and ram :/ I also disabled it for now.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have problems with slow and memory consuming mypy too. I have a guess that it may be because VSCode is trying to index a rather large mypy_cache. I added the cache to the settings in the `"files.exclude"` and `"python.linting.ignorePatterns"` sections and it got better